# Income inequality indices

Tags: data-request, inequality, welfare-economics

I would be thankful for suggestions for standard inequality measurements such as Gini coefficient and Palma ratio. I would like to make a comparison across different countries simultaneously, hence I am looking for something standardised, which in best case scenario is published annually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The World Inequality Database may be of interest for you: https://wid.world/. I guess it is also worthwhile to check the statistical databases of international institutions such as the EU, OECD, IMF and WorldBank.